# SQL Permissions to create table from asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I have a web service that performs sql functions when invoked by windows apps and that all works fine as long as it is `Inserts`, `Updates`, and `Deletes`. However, I would like to be able to have one of the methods to `DROP` and `CREATE TABLE`. When I do this I get the following error returned:

```
User does not have permission to perform this action.
CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors.
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'et-live'.
```

I checked the `User.Identity.Name` in the web method but it is blank (null). How can I get the web service to Drop and Create tables?

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL Instance? If so, you will need to give the user `ddl_admin` rights to be able to create/drop tables.

Comment: Yes as a matter of fact I do have access to the sql instance.

Comment: In that case, you will need to make the user a `ddl_admin`.[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986854.aspx) is a good primer on adding/updating roles for users.

Comment: That's where i'm a little confused because when I check for the username in the method on the web service there is none. I'll check out the link.

Comment: I would think you should be looking for the credentials in your connection string.

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically drop and create tables? This sounds like a poor design decision to me. If anything, use temp tables instead of persistent tables that behave like temp tables.

Comment: If you're using integrated security to connect to the SQL server, the account used to connect to the Server will be the identity on the Application Pool

Comment: @Spock The Application Pool was the answer. In SSMS > Security > Logins > IIS APPPOOL\Folder, I granted permission in Properties > User Mapping. Can you create an answer to the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using integrated security to connect to the SQL server, the account used to connect to the Server will be the identity on the Application Pool.

Taken from comments...

```
In SSMS > Security > Logins > IIS APPPOOL\Folder,
Granted permission in Properties > User Mapping.
```